# Getting 403 for Intune API request for managedAppPolicies endpoint but not others (i.e. groups)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Below are the queries that we ran. They are both beta endpoints but I am not able to authenticate to the managedAppPolicies endpoint. The same auth details previously worked. Were there changes to the permissions?

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedAppPolicies/
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ------

Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Application is not authorized to perform this operation - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: b8c9fdff-b1f5-4f36-847e-d31d35c81f65 - Url: https://fef.amsua0502.manage.microsoft.com/MAMAdmin/MAMAdminFEService/managedAppPolicies?api-version=2016-06-16 - CustomApiErrorPhrase: ",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b8c9fdff-b1f5-4f36-847e-d31d35c81f65",
      "date": "2017-05-12T14:50:24"
    }
  }
}

-----------------------------
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
 - THIS WORKS FINE
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer -------

Response:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "480535ce-03c5-421d-a350-fb7e133b9dc3",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "classification": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2017-02-23T07:51:24Z",
      "description": "Self help community for library",
      "displayName": "Library Assist",
      "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
      ],
      "mail": "library@evomobility.onmicrosoft.com",
      "mailEnabled": true,
      "mailNickname": "library",
      "membershipRule": null,
      "membershipRuleProcessingState": null,
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
      "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:library@evomobility.onmicrosoft.com"
      ],
      "renewedDateTime": "2017-02-23T07:51:24Z",
      "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
      "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
      "securityEnabled": false,
      "theme": null,
      "visibility": "Public"
    },
    {
      "id": "548dc0b3-316f-41e1-8bda-e50b70e446ac",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "classification": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2017-03-08T21:07:26Z",
      "description": "This is an updated description",
      "displayName": "CDB TEST USER GROUP 1",
      "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
      ],
      "mail": "654637b5-c2cd-4542-b98d-3d857f4987df@evomobility.onmicrosoft.com",
      "mailEnabled": true,
      "mailNickname": "654637b5-c2cd-4542-b98d-3d857f4987df",
      "membershipRule": null,
      "membershipRuleProcessingState": null,
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
      "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:654637b5-c2cd-4542-b98d-3d857f4987df@evomobility.onmicrosoft.com"
      ],
      "renewedDateTime": "2017-03-08T21:07:26Z",
      "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
      "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
      "securityEnabled": true,
      "theme": null,
      "visibility": "Public"
    },
    {
      "id": "a61214d7-4b0c-421e-86dd-966fcf7c9908",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "classification": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2017-01-24T19:33:53Z",
      "description": "This is auto generated security for O365 MDM policy",
      "displayName": "Default MDM security group",
      "groupTypes": [],
      "mail": null,
      "mailEnabled": false,
      "mailNickname": "BposMailNickName",
      "membershipRule": null,
      "membershipRuleProcessingState": null,
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
      "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "proxyAddresses": [],
      "renewedDateTime": "2017-01-24T19:33:53Z",
      "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
      "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
      "securityEnabled": true,
      "theme": null,
      "visibility": null
    },
    {
      "id": "f64a6ae8-b234-4d99-9ddb-6379016e2c66",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "classification": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2017-04-25T19:19:12Z",
      "description": "TestUser1 ",
      "displayName": "TestUser1",
      "groupTypes": [],
      "mail": null,
      "mailEnabled": false,
      "mailNickname": "677a30f1-c00b-40b1-a023-887d916ff7f3",
      "membershipRule": null,
      "membershipRuleProcessingState": null,
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
      "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "proxyAddresses": [],
      "renewedDateTime": "2017-04-25T19:19:12Z",
      "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
      "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
      "securityEnabled": true,
      "theme": null,
      "visibility": null
    },
    {
      "id": "fa41896d-b61b-4c59-9ba3-6594b570ce80",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "classification": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2017-01-20T20:07:59Z",
      "description": null,
      "displayName": "Test Users Group",
      "groupTypes": [],
      "mail": null,
      "mailEnabled": false,
      "mailNickname": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "membershipRule": null,
      "membershipRuleProcessingState": null,
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
      "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "proxyAddresses": [],
      "renewedDateTime": "2017-01-20T20:07:59Z",
      "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
      "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
      "securityEnabled": true,
      "theme": null,
      "visibility": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/managedAppPolicies/

NOTE: You need Admin access in Intune instance. When you fetch the token, see if you have scope details that includes either one of following scope: DeviceManagementApps.Read.All DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All